# JTAG Electrical Requirements & Pins Required

Tags: jtag, specifications

I'm a beginner designing a USB TO UART/ JTAG CONVERTER using FT2232H. I'm planning to use the TMS, TDI, TDO, TCK signals by directly connecting them to a header.

I'm doubtful about this method. So, I would like to know the following:

1. Are these 4 lines enough for the complete utility of JTAG or some
   other pins like RESET are required?
2. Do I need to connect some resistors, capacitors, protection devices to my lines?
3. Do I need to use a buffer?

If possible, somebody please share the official document containing the electrical specifications of JTAG.

Comment: Did you type 'jtag specification' into Google?   Anyway, here's an appnote from a company which makes jtag test kit:  http://www.xjtag.com/support-jtag/jtag-technical-guide.php

Comment: Shouldn't you copy one of the existing designs e.g. http://openocd.org/doc/html/Debug-Adapter-Hardware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are intending to use [Boundary Scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_scan) and the short answer is:

**Yes**. The four lines (TCK, TMS, TDI and TDO) are completely sufficient, and indeed these are the four **required** interface pins.

TRST (Test Reset or Test logic Reset, depending on who you ask), which holds the boundary scan state machine in reset, is *optional*.

When I am designing with devices that do not have TRST, I usually pull TCK *low*, as this prevents a potential power-up race condition.

To operate the scan chain, you may need to read up on [BSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_scan_description_language).

Tip of the hat to Simon Richter - it is indeed nice to have a way to pull the system reset line on a debugger. Good point.

Comment: In general it is nice to have a way for the JTAG debugger to pull the regular system reset line directly if you are using an an OCD.

Comment: which pin of FT2232H to be used as TRST#?